# MySql query slows down

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have a table (`cumulative_energy_consumptions`) defined as:

```
id int(11) pk
sensor_id int(11) fk
value decimal
recorded_at datetime
```

with two indexes, one on sensor_id, the other on (sensor_id, recorded_at) and it uses InnoDB engine.

Given a sensor and a datetime, I have to find the row with the maximum 'recorded_at' before that datetime.
It can be solved with the following query:

```
    SELECT MAX(recorded_at)
    FROM cumulative_energy_consumptions
    WHERE sensor_id = 88 AND recorded_at <= '2016-06-29 00:00:00'
```

and it is incredibly fast (0.00030 s on my machine), even with a very chatty sensor (id 88) that has more than 300k records.

Instead of a single sensor, I wrote the following query to get the result for many sensors at once:

```
    SELECT sensor_id, MAX(recorded_at) AS first_before
            FROM cumulative_energy_consumptions
            WHERE 
                sensor_id IN (80, 85, 88, 89) 
                AND 
                recorded_at <= '2016-07-10 00:00:00' 
            GROUP BY sensor_id
```

and it is also very very fast (0.00055 s)

Now I was trying to write the query for one sensor and many datetimes, and I tried that:

```
SELECT input_times.*, (
        SELECT MAX(recorded_at)
        FROM cumulative_energy_consumptions
        WHERE sensor_id = 88 AND recorded_at <= input_times.instant
    ) as res
FROM
    (
        SELECT '2016-06-29 00:00:00' as instant
--      UNION SELECT '2016-06-30 00:00:00' as instant
--    UNION SELECT '2016-07-01 00:00:00' as instant
--    UNION SELECT '2016-07-02 00:00:00' as instant
   ) as input_times
```

when the table created using unions has only one row, it takes 0.0004s and I was expecting that with two rows it would have taken roughly the double, but it completes in 0.2 s; with 4 rows it takes 0.4s and so on.

Why does MySql uses a different strategy with multiple rows instead of applying the strategy for one row many times? Is there a way to rewrite this query to make it as fast as expected?

Thank you

Comment: I'd try a join first. Something like: `SELECT input_times.instant, sensor_id, MAX(recorded_at) AS first_before
            FROM (SELECT '2016-06-29 00:00:00' as instant UNION ALL ...) AS input_times CROSS JOIN cumulative_energy_consumptions
            WHERE 
                sensor_id IN (80, 85, 88, 89) 
                AND 
                recorded_at <=  input_times.instant
            GROUP BY input_times.instant, sensor_id;`

Comment: hank you a lot, but the query is still slow as before. It does a range index scan. I also tried to change the index to unique without any result. Should I try to change my dbms?

Comment: Can you please include the explain output of the queries? What version of mysql are you using? What is the value of `optimizer_switch`? By the way sensor_id index is superfluous because you already have it in (sensor_id, recorded_at) index.

Comment: mysql version: 5.7.11

`index_merge=on,
index_merge_union=on,
index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw/iBdJy1mz
here you can find the explain for the @ypercubeᵀᴹ comment

Answer (score 1):

Try this rewriting. It avoids the `GROUP BY` and should be using the index on `(sensor_id, recorded_at)` for both the subquery and the join:

```
SELECT 
    input_times.instant, 
    c.sensor_id, 
    c.recorded_at AS first_before,
    c.value 
FROM 
    ( SELECT 80 AS sensor_id UNION ALL
      SELECT 85  UNION ALL
      SELECT 88  UNION ALL
      SELECT 89
    ) AS s
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT '2016-06-29 00:00:00' AS instant 
      UNION ALL 
      ...
    ) AS input_times
  JOIN  
    cumulative_energy_consumptions AS c
  ON  c.sensor_id = s.sensor_id
  AND c.recorded_at = ( SELECT ci.recorded_at 
                        FROM cumulative_energy_consumptions AS ci
                        WHERE ci.sensor_id = s.sensor_id
                          AND ci.recorded_at <= input_times.instant 
                        ORDER BY ci.recorded_at DESC
                        LIMIT 1
                      ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot again!
This time the query is even slower than before (1.11s vs 0.45s)
http://pastebin.com/raw/5m9kHAVM here you can find the explain output

Comment: Is it slow, too, if you remove the `c.value` from the select list? And did you try the various queries with the change suggested by Rick?

Comment: At the moment I'm working with a simplified table (see my comment to Rick's answer) and the query performances are the same.

Comment: I also tried to created another index on (recorded_at, sensor_id) and forcing the query to use it, without any result. Things are getting worse if I use as input a date in august (instead of july): I think this means that under the hood MySQL performs a full scan up to the input date. I'm trying to understand if [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) I can find the solution

Answer (score 1):

This may help the other suggestions, so do it regardless.

Get rid if `id`:

```
CREATE TABLE cumulative_energy_consumptions (
    sensor_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- note: smaller
    value ... NOT NULL,
    recorded_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(sensor_id, recorded_at)  -- changed
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

You did mention the details of the datatype for `value`.  Don't get excessive on the number of digits if you use `DECIMAL`.  Also, consider `FLOAT` as an alternative.  (Do *not* use `FLOAT(m,n)`.)

The `UNION` of a single column is a terrible idea.  `WHERE recorded_at IN ('...', '...', ...)` much better.  But if `recorded_at <= '2016-07-10 00:00:00'` is "correct", then use it.

Beware of any time less than 1ms.  It could be going through the Query cache and not actually running the query.  Use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` to get 'fair' timings.

Comment: I created another table called 'cumulative_dup' following all your guidelines, but nothing really changed. I also dropped "value" column to be sure that its does not create any issue

Comment: SQL_NO_CACHE does not affect my timings: every sub-millisecond query is still as fast as before. In those cases MySQL does a very great job with indexes, but it seems to ignore them as we add more datetime values as input

Comment: When asking for more than about 20% of a table, the index is ignored since it is likely to be faster to do a table scan.  (The 20% is not a fixed number.)